# Using Elasticsearch analyzers to reduce text length

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch to create an index:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_shards": 1,
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "max_token_length": 3,
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop",
            "english_stemmer",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "stopwords": "english"
        },
        "english_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which is creating the index `my_index`, with one field `Text`. Since I using the `my_custom_analyzer` analyzer, I was though that each indexed document inside of the index will be stored on the minimized form of it. For example, this sentence:

```
a quick fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

will be stored without the stopwords ("a", and "the").

But, after adding this document:

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{
  "Text": "a quick fox jumps over the lazy dog"
}
```

and running this query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Text": {
        "query": "a the", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting this response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.5753642,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "Text" : "a quick fox jumps over the lazy dog"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What is missing to me here?

1. As you can see, I still can make search with stopwords ("a the") and still catch the result. How? If I deducted the stopwords from the index. Expected - nothing will come back.
2. The text field contain the original text. Expected, it won't stored in the full version but the minimized version (without stopwords e.g.).

Can someone explain me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Please note that your mapping defines a `text` field (lowercase) and your document and query operate on the `Text` field (initial uppercase), which means it's a different one with the standard analyzer which doesn't have a stopwords token filter

Comment: @Val Thanks for let me know. I was just fixing the Type. Seems like its not changing the behavior that was observed earlier. So the question is still open.

Comment: You need to recreate your index and mapping and reindex your data, as you cannot change the analyzer of an existing field. I've reproduced your index and sample doc and the query returns nothing, which means it's working

Comment: @Val "my_index" is a new index. Started empty. So I believe that reindex might be redundant

Comment: I tested your code in your question and it worked, i.e. stopwords are not indexed and the query yields nothing. Please try again

Comment: @Val, question. Assuming the analyzer is working correctly (e.g. not indexing stopwords), the `Text` field will have the full version (e.g. including "a" and "the" - stopwords) of the document anyway? Is this possible to deduct them from the `Text` field too? so the storage will be smaller...

Comment: If you mean the value of the `Text` field in the `_source` document, that will not change, only what's indexed. However, you can create an ingest pipeline that can modify the content of the `Text` field to remove stopwords manually if you want.